# Can a Pod tolerate one of a set of taints

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Consider a cluster in which each node has a given taint (let's say `NodeType`) and a Pod can tolerate a set of `NodeType`. For example, there are nodes tainted `NodeType=A`, `NodeType=B` and `NodeType=C`.

I'd like to be able to specify for example that some Pods tolerate `NodeType=A` or `NodeType=C`, but not `NodeType=B`. Other Pods (in different Deployments) would tolerate different sets. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: When you write "some pods", do you mean pods belonging to a single deployment or multiple deployments?

Comment: Multiple deployments. I'll edit that in, thanks

Comment: I see you have a couple of answers already. For pods in multiple deployments, it is possible. Very much along the same lines mentioned in the answers already. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it appears it is possible to do so by adding multiple tolerations with the same key on the pod's spec. An example of the same is given in the official [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/#concepts).

Here is a demo I tried which works to produce the desired result.

The cluster has three nodes:

```
kubectl get nodes
NAME      STATUS   AGE     VERSION
dummy-0   Ready    3m17s   v1.17.14
dummy-1   Ready    26m     v1.17.14
dummy-2   Ready    26m     v1.17.14
```

I tainted them as mentioned in the question using the `kubectl taint` command:

```
kubectl taint node dummy-0 NodeType=A:NoSchedule
kubectl taint node dummy-1 NodeType=B:NoSchedule
kubectl taint node dummy-2 NodeType=C:NoSchedule
```

Created a Deployment with three replicas with the matching tolerations:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx-nfs
      tolerations:
      - key: "NodeType"
        operator: "Equal"
        value: "A"
        effect: "NoSchedule"
      - key: "NodeType"
        operator: "Equal"
        value: "B"
        effect: "NoSchedule"
```

From the `kubectl get pods` command, we can see that the pods of the Deployment were scheduled only on the nodes `dummy-0` and `dummy-1` and not on `dummy-2` which has a different taint:

```
kubectl get pod -o wide
NAME                               READY  STATUS  RESTARTS AGE      IP         NODE
nginx-deployment-5fc8f985d8-2pfvm   1/1   Running    0      8s  100.96.2.11   dummy-0
nginx-deployment-5fc8f985d8-hkrcz   1/1   Running    0      8s  100.96.6.10   dummy-1
nginx-deployment-5fc8f985d8-xfxsx   1/1   Running    0      8s  100.96.6.11   dummy-1
```

Further, it is important to understand that the taints and tolerations are useful to make sure that the pods don't get scheduled to a particular node.

We should use the concepts of [node affinities namely affinity and anti-affinity](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2017/03/advanced-scheduling-in-kubernetes/) to make sure that the pods are scheduled to a particular node.